# Constants class or propeties file for declaring url mappings?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is there any strong reasons to choose one over the other when declaring the mappings for url resources?

```
@RequestMapping(Mappings.USER)
```

vs

```
@RequestMapping("${mappings.user}")
```

I understand that property files can be modified after deployment, and that might be a reason to keep it in properties if you want it to be changed easily, right? But also I think changing them easily could be undesirable. So for those with experience, which do you prefer, and why? I think a constants file might be easier to refactor, like if I wanted to change the name of a resource I would only have to refactor inside the constants class vs if I refactored properties I would have to refactor in the properties file and everywhere that uses the mapping (Im using eclipse and as far as I know it doesnt have property name refactoring like that). Or maybe a third option of neither and declaring them all as literals inside the controllers?

Comment: I edited your question to remove the "bonus question". Please stay on point by not wedging multiple, unrelated questions into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your use case. If you need the change URIs without recompilation, property files is the way to go. Otherwise, constants provide type safety and ease of unit testing that SPEL doesn't. If you're not gonna change or reuse them (for example, same URI for GET and POST is very common), I don't see any need for constants at all.